# Matching a parameterized test with pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm use pytest with some parameterized tests. However, in more recent versions of pytest with keywords matching becoming more complex I can't figure out how to match a specific paramterization of the test.

If I run my tests they look like

```
test_abc[backend_generator0-1]
test_abc[backend_generator0-2]
```

etc. But I can't figure out how to run a specific test parameterization.

```
pytest -k "test_abc[backend_generator0-2]"
```

gives Syntax Error

> test_simple_delay[backend_generator1not 2]

I've tried various attempts at escaping the `-` to match only the specific test but without success.

This python 2.7 on pytest 2.3.5

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `-k` or escapes for this. Use the node ID directly:

`py.test 'test_abc[backend_generator0-1]'`

Comment: See http://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html#selecting-tests-based-on-their-node-id for more on node IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `py.test -k "test_abc and generator0"` i guess.